# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'each' function

Tags: javascript, function, backbone.js, each

Hey guys here is my js file and I am taking error message about each function at line:24 and  I do not know why I couldnt find whats wrong. I am just trying to see the list of items on the console.log panel but it does not even give me list on the html page.

```
(function() {

    window.App = {

        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {}
    };

    window.template = function(id){
        return _.template( $('#' + id).html() );
    };

App.Models.Task = Backbone.Model.extend({});

App.Collections.Task = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Task
});

App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    render: function(){
        this.collection.each( this.addOne, this);

        return this;
    },

    addOne: function(task){
        //creating new child view
        var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model: task });

        //append to the root element
        this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
    }
});

App.Views.Task = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: template('taskTemplate'),

    events: {
        'click .edit': 'editTask'
    },

    editTask: function(){
        alert('you are editing the tas.');
    },

    render: function(){
        var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );
        this.$el.html(template);
        return this;
    }

});


var tasksCollection = new App.Views.Task([
{
    title: 'Go to the store',
    priority: 4
},
{
    title: 'Go to the mall',
    priority: 3
},
{
    title: 'get to work',
    priority: 5
}
]);

var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({ collection: tasksCollection });

$('.tasks').html(tasksView.render().el);

})();
```

Comment: did you include underscore in your js file?  Can you check the console for what the this.collection is on that line.

Comment: which line is line 24?

Comment: @JanDvorak i assume the only line in the code that uses `each`

Comment: ah, thanks. But why would `this.collection` be `window`?

Comment: Where did you try a `console.log`? Please include that in your code and post the result.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a view instance as though it was a class:

```
App.Views.Tasks = Backbone.View.extend({ /* ... */ });

var tasksCollection = new App.Views.Task([
{
    title: 'Go to the store',
    priority: 4
},
//...
```

and then you create another instance of that view and hand it `tasksCollection` as though it really was a collection:

```
var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({ collection: tasksCollection });
```

But views and collections are different things and only collection's have an `each` method (unless you add an `each` to your view of course).

You want to create `tasksCollection` as an `App.Collections.Task`:

```
var tasksCollection = new App.Collections.Task([
{
    title: 'Go to the store',
    priority: 4
},
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is happening cus your **each** method not able to find the collection. As well the singular Task to Tasks

At this line:
Change this

```
var tasksCollection = new App.Views.Task([
```

TO, this:

```
var tasksCollection = new App.Collections.Tasks([
```